# Which parameter type should I choose? A generic that extends a supertype or the supertype

Tags: java, generics, methods

Below I have a driver that calls two methods.  The first method's parameter type is a generic type that extends Polygon.  The second method's parameter type is Polygon.  Both require me to cast the argument in order to call a subclass method.  Which is better?  Why should I use one over the other?

```
public class Driver {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

                Square s1;
                try {
                        s1 = new Square(new Point(0,0), new Point(0,1), new Point(1,1), new Point(1,0));
                }
                catch (IllFormedPolygonException e) {
                        System.out.println(e.toString());
                        return;
                }

                System.out.println(s1.toString());
                printArea(s1);
                printArea2(s1);
        }

        public static <T extends Polygon> void printArea(T poly) {
                System.out.println(poly.getArea());

                if (poly instanceof Triangle) {
                        ((Triangle)poly).doTriangleThing();
                }
                else if (poly instanceof Square) {
                        ((Square)poly).doSquareThing();
                }
                else {
                        System.out.println("Is polygon");
                }
        }

        public static void printArea2(Polygon poly) {
                System.out.println(poly.getArea());

                if (poly instanceof Triangle) {
                        ((Triangle)poly).doTriangleThing();
                }
                else if (poly instanceof Square) {
                        ((Square)poly).doSquareThing();
                }
                else {
                        System.out.println("Is polygon");
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose the super type. From the [generics tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html):

> Generic methods allow type parameters to be used to express dependencies among the types of one or more arguments to a method and/or its return type. If there isn't such a dependency, a generic method should not be used.

If there is no relationship between the arguments/return type then the generic doesn't add anything; it just makes the code harder to read and so the simpler solution should be preferred.

Here's an example where a generic method *is* useful. say you have a method that takes a `Polygon` and returns a copy that is half the size. Because the return type is the same as the parameter type generics can be used to avoid casts in client code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Square square = new Square(0, 0, 10, 10);

    // Without the generic it's necessary to cast the return value
    square = (Square) shrink(square);

    // Cast not needed with generic
    square = shrinkWithGenerics(square);
}

public static Polygon shrink(Polygon poly) {
    // ...
}

public static <T extends Polygon> T shrinkWithGenerics(T poly) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I think I get it.  So, I use generics in methods when I need to stipulate that multiple arguments have the same type OR the type of certain arguments and the type of the object returned must be the same?

Comment: That's exactly it. I've added an example to the answer to illustrate where generics are of use.

Answer (score 2):

As a [@teppic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3591528/teppic) says there is actually no reason to use generics here.

That said if you have access to the `Polygon`, `Square` and `Triangle` classes I'd urgently redesign them so that you don't have to write `instance of` at all!

First define `printArea()` in `Polygon` class and necessary overrides in subclasses and/or define an additional interface for printable polygons.

Second if you can't modify these classes or only the `Polygon` class you may still try to extend the `Polygon` class (= make your own, more smarter) or wrap it into eg. a SmartPolygon to which you bind a `delegate` Polygon (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_(object-oriented_programming) or simply make it accessible with a getter `getPolygon()`. Then do the first point here above using this new class.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice.